# Why QDialog not shows any widgets until job completed?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, qdialog

im new to pyqt5,i tried to open dialog and push some text into that dialog

my dialog contain one plaintext ,progressbar and pushbutton

when i run the code its popup the dialog but not shown any thing ,after code execution completes its showing all the widgets and with text

but i need to open the dialog and i want update progress bar

My code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog,QPlainTextEdit,QScrollArea,QProgressBar,QPushButton)
import sys
import time
class PrograssDialog():
    def ShowDialog(self,Dialogs):
        try:
            self.Pd=Dialogs
            self.Pd.setWindowTitle("Script Excution... ")
            self.Pd.resize(500,500)        
            self.ScrArea=QScrollArea(self.Pd)
            self.ScrArea.move(0,0)
            self.ScrArea.resize(500,300)
            self.TextArea=QPlainTextEdit(self.Pd)
            self.TextArea.move(0,0)
            self.TextArea.resize(500,300)
            self.TextArea.insertPlainText(str("Start : %s" % time.ctime())+"\n")
            self.Prograssbar=QProgressBar(self.Pd)
            self.Prograssbar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 350, 450, 23))
            self.Prograssbar.setMaximum(100) 
            self.Cancelbutton=QPushButton("Cancel",self.Pd)
            self.Cancelbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 400, 93, 28))
            self.Cancelbutton.clicked.connect(self.StopExcution)   
            self.Pd.show()
        except Exception as msg:
            import sys
            tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
            print("Error_analysis " + str(msg)+ str(tb.tb_lineno)) 
    def AddMessage(self,Message):
        self.TextArea.insertPlainText(str(Message)+"\n")
        # print("message added")
    def SetPercentage(self,Number):
        self.Prograssbar.setValue(Number)
        # print("percent added")
    def StopExcution(self):
        sys.exit()       
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui=PrograssDialog()
ui.ShowDialog(QDialog())
for i in range(100):
    ui.AddMessage("Hello")
    ui.SetPercentage(i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your `for` loop blocks the Qt event loop.  Hence no changes will be visible until the `for` loop completes and the `app.exec()` statement executes.  If you need timed updates consider using a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various problems with your code, I'll try to address all of them.

1. The main reason for the issue you are facing is that **no** blocking functions (like `time.sleep`) should happen in the main Qt thread (which is the thread that shows the GUI elements and allow interactions with them); blocking functions prevent the UI to correctly draw and refresh its contents, if you want to do an operation at specific intervals, you have to use a [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html);
2. You should not use a basic python object subclass for this kind of situations, especially since you're only using just *one* dialog; you should subclass from QDialog instead and implement
3. To "exit" your program you should not use `sys.exit` (you are already using it), but use [`QApplication.quit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) instead; also, since you already imported `sys` at the beginning, there's no need to import it again in the exception;
4. Function and variable names should *not* be capitalized; while you can use any casing style you want for your own code, it's common (and highly suggested) practice to always use lowercase initials, and it's also a convention you should stick to when sharing code with others, especially on Q&A sites like StackOverflow; read more on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/);
5. Always avoid fixed geometries for children widgets: what others see on their computers will probably be very different from what you see on yours, and you might end up with an unusable interface; use layout managers instead, so that the widgets can resize themselves if required;
6. You added a scroll area but you never use it; since you're using the same geometry for the text area I believe that you thought you were using for that, but there's no need as the text area already *is* a scroll area;

Here is how the code could look like in order to achieve what you want:

```
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class ProgressDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.textArea = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.textArea)
        self.textArea.insertPlainText(str("Start : %s" % time.ctime())+"\n")
        self.textArea.setReadOnly(True)

        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        self.cancelButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel')
        layout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)

        self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.QApplication.quit)
        self.countTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.countTimer.timeout.connect(self.timeout)

    def startCounter(self, maximum, sleepSeconds):
        self.progressBar.reset()
        self.progressBar.setMaximum(maximum)
        # QTimer interval is in milliseconds
        self.countTimer.setInterval(sleepSeconds * 1000)
        self.countTimer.start()

    def timeout(self):
        if self.progressBar.value() == self.progressBar.maximum():
            self.countTimer.stop()
            return
        self.setPercentage(self.progressBar.value() + 1)
        self.addMessage('Hello')

    def setPercentage(self, value):
        self.progressBar.setValue(value)

    def addMessage(self, message):
        self.textArea.insertPlainText(str(message) + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = ProgressDialog()
    dialog.show()
    dialog.startCounter(100, .5)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```